# Migrar função PHP de mcrypt para Openssl

Tags: php, funções, criptografia, openssl, mcrypt

Tenho uma função em PHP que utiliza o mcrypt.
O problema é que o PHP 7.2 não aceita mais o mcrypt...
Alguém sabe como refazê-la de modo a obter o mesmo resultado utilizando o Openssl?

```
function Encript($Val, $chave){

    $cifrado = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
    $modo = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;
    $Cript = mcrypt_encrypt($cifrado, $chave, $Val, $modo, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($cifrado, $modo), MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM));
    return base64_encode($Cript);

}

function Decript($Val, $chave){

    $Base = base64_decode($Val);

    $cifrado = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
    $modo = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;
    return mcrypt_decrypt($cifrado, $chave, $Base, $modo, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($cifrado, $modo), MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente, você precisará criptografar novamente todos os seus dados e na verdade desde de PHP 7.1.0, o mcrypt_decrypt e o mcrypt_encrypt estão depreciados, sendo assim para resolver o teu problema você precisa usar o  openssl_encrypt e o openssl_decrypt, algo como isto.

```
$string="string";
$chave="chave";
$encrypted_string=openssl_encrypt($string,"AES-128-ECB",$chave);
$decrypted_string=openssl_decrypt($encrypted_string,"AES-128-ECB",$chave);
```

Só lembrando ECB não é totalmente seguro, mas é simples. [Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php) :

Comment: Poderia ter apenas corridigo, mas tudo bem, acabou passando despercebido.

Comment: Veja se a alteração atende ao que você queria.

Answer (score 1):

Não há como portar para o OpenSSL. Isso ocorre porque o `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` não é igual ao `AES-256`, ele usa uma versão não-padrão. O AES opera sempre com blocos tamanho de 128 bytes, mesmo no AES-256, isso não ocorre no MCrypt, que usa blocos maiores. O AES-256 é mais vulnerável do que o AES-128 [em alguns tipos de ataques](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/317), mas a construção do MCrypt é ainda menos estudada, o que o torna menos seguro.

Uma outra observação é o uso do ECB, **nunca use ECB**, [você consegue ver o penguim crifrado](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/). Além disso, o modo usado não garante integridade da informação, é ainda possível mudar o texto cifrado.

---

Você tem duas opções:

1.Use OpenSSL com AES-256-GCM:

```
$nonce = random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length("aes-256-gcm")); // Há riscos de colisão devido ao pequeno tamanho!
$cifrado = openssl_encrypt($Val, "aes-256-gcm", $chave, '', $nonce, $tag);

$original = openssl_decrypt($cifrado, "aes-256-gcm", $chave, '', $nonce, $tag);
```

2.Use LibSodium com XChaCha20Poly1305 (recomendado):

```
$nonce = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_XCHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES);
$cifrado = sodium_crypto_aead_xchacha20poly1305_ietf_encrypt($Val, '', $nonce, $chave);


$original = sodium_crypto_aead_xchacha20poly1305_ietf_decrypt($cifrado, '', $nonce, $chave);
```

Em qualquer um dos dois é preciso que decifre e cifre novamente, preferencialmente com novas chaves.