# Quais as alternativas para as funções do tipo mcrypt_*?

Tags: php, mcrypt

As funções do tipo `mcrypt_*` foram descontinuadas no PHP 7.1.0 e removidas no PHP 7.2.0 como se pode ver no [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php):

> Warning This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 7.1.0, and REMOVED in PHP
>   7.2.0.

Estava a ver esta pergunta [Migrar função PHP de mcrypt para Openssl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318865/7210) mas só tem ai uma alternativa de migração. **Que outras alternativas há?**

Para dar um contexto melhor eu tenho umas funções bem antigas para encriptar strings, como por exemplo, algumas strings que vão por GET com informação que eu não quero que o cliente veja.

Ou seja, em vez de apresentar o id (ou outra string qualquer)

> meusite.pt/user/edit/&id=354

Apresenta uma encriptação para que o cliente não invente:

> meusite.pt/user/edit/&id=5x6ypIpvj6Wd9TpekI2s4DetXUgBTSpZ_cyEAJxxBVU

As funções que uso atualmente são estas:

```
public function encode( $text )
{
    $myKey = "stackoverflowemportugues";

    if( !$text )
        return false;

    $iv_size   = mcrypt_get_iv_size( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB );
    $iv        = mcrypt_create_iv( $iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND );
    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $myKey,
                                $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv );

    return trim( base64_encode( $crypttext ) );
}

public function decode( $text )
{
    $myKey = "stackoverflowemportugues";

    if( !$text )
        return false;

    $crypttext   = base64_decode( $text );
    $iv_size     = mcrypt_get_iv_size( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB );
    $iv          = mcrypt_create_iv( $iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND );
    $decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $myKey,
                                  $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv );

    return trim( $decrypttext );
}
```

*PS: Já agora se quiserem aprimorar a resposta podem fazer uma migração das funções, para ficar mais completo.*

Comment: Creio que melhor que conversão direta seja analisar o que é melhor para cada uso específico.

Comment: Uma string em base 64 não deveria conter um texto, né? Então por que o `trim`?

Comment: @Costamilam sim, mas isso não é muito importante para a questão.

Comment: Você pode usar: [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: @IvanFerrer eu não mencionei as funções do tipo `password_*` porque não faz sentido neste caso, eu já as uso quando mexo com passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro existe alguns problemas no código original, como o uso do modo ECB. Segundo, isso depende da versão que está utilizando, estou considerando que está usando PHP 7.2.

---

Infelizmente, uma alternativa compatível não há, não "nativamente". Isso porque está usando o `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`. O AES, que é a padronização do Rijndael, utiliza um bloco de 128-bit em todos os modos (AES-128, AES-192 e AES-256). Enquanto isso, o `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` utiliza blocos de também 256 bits, por isso é incompatível.

Portar do `MCRYPT` para `OpenSSL` é possível em um único caso. Se estiver utilizando o `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`, [pode ver isso na prática aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/430123/15089). Então se estiver usando este algoritmo poderá migrar para o OpenSSL usando o `AES-128`, que serão equivalentes.

Nenhuma das APIs atuais (como OpenSSL e Sodium) expõe o Rijndael diretamente, ao menos até onde tenho conhecimento. Então, para migrar teria que decifrar todos os textos e migrar para um outro algorítimo e API.

---

Existem duas alternativas (considerando criptografia de chave-privada/simétrica):

- OpenSSL (*que utilizará* usar AES ou Camellia)
- LibSodium (*que utilizará* Salsa20, XSalsa20, ChaCha20, XChaCha20 ou AES)

---

O LibSodium utiliza algoritmos "mais performáticos" (ignorando AES-NI, inclusive ele só funciona com AES se o CPU tal instrução!) e tem preferencia para cifra de fluxos e encriptações autenticadas (usando Poly1035, ou GCM para AES). Minha resposta poderá ser tendenciosa, já que prefiro severamente o Sodium do que o arcaico OpenSSL...

---

Considerando que seus objetivos sejam:

- Encriptar uma mensagem usando uma chave simétrica (ambas as pessoas sabem a mesma chave) e impedir pessoas que desconhecem a chave de ler o conteúdo da mensagem.
- Autenticar a mensagem usando uma chave simétrica (ambas as pessoas sabem a mesma chave) e impedir que pessoas sem tal chave sejam capaz de alterar o texto cifrado. Enfim, garantido que a mensagem não foi alterada por alguém que não tenha a chave.

O [LibSodium, nativo no PHP 7.2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php), provê uma API muito mais fácil de usar, e pode usa-lo da seguinte forma:

```
public function encode($text) {
    $key = "stackoverflowemportugues";  // Sua chave-secreta que tem que ter 256 bits, gere uma usando o random_bytes!
    $nonce = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES);

    return $nonce . sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_encrypt($text , "", $nonce , $key);
}
```

```
public function decode($text) {
    $key = "stackoverflowemportugues"; // Sua chave-secreta que tem que ter 256 bits, gere uma usando o random_bytes!
    $nonce = mb_substr($text, 0, SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES, '8bit');

    $decoded = sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_decrypt(mb_substr($text, SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES, mb_strlen($text, '8bit'), '8bit'), "", $nonce, $key);
    if ($decoded === false) {
         throw new Exception("A autenticação deu errado, provavelmente a mensagem foi alterada!");
    }

    return $decoded;
}
```

> Preciso ainda testar, mas não possuo mais PHP instalado. :\

*O resultado talvez precise ser codificado pra algum formato amigável, como o base64, hex (...), dependendo do seu caso de uso. Atualmente acredito que o resultado do `encode` será em binário e a entrada do `decode` também é suposta a ser binário.*

Este exemplo acima irá utilizar a variante do ChaCha20 com 96 bits de nonce, assim evitando colisão de nonce. O original (`sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt`, sem o `_ietf_`) possui apenas 64 bits. Essa construção usa `encrypt-then-mac`, por isso se a mensagem, se modificada, não será lida, nem parcialmente.

Isto é equivalente à utilizar o AES-GCM.

Answer (score -2):

Aqui está uma solução para o que você precisa:

```
public function encode($encrypt, $key, $iv) {
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($encrypt, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0, $iv);
    return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}

public function decode($decrypt, $key) {
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($decrypt), 2);
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0, $iv);
}
```

[Referência aqui](https://www.shift8web.ca/2017/04/how-to-encrypt-and-execute-your-php-code-with-mcrypt/).

Mas eu sugiro fazer uma implementação futura para usar password_hash:

```
function password_hash($password, $algo, array $options = array()) {
        if (!function_exists('crypt')) {
            trigger_error("Crypt must be loaded for password_hash to function", E_USER_WARNING);
            return null;
        }
        if (!is_string($password)) {
            trigger_error("password_hash(): Password must be a string", E_USER_WARNING);
            return null;
        }
        if (!is_int($algo)) {
            trigger_error("password_hash() expects parameter 2 to be long, " . gettype($algo) . " given", E_USER_WARNING);
            return null;
        }
        switch ($algo) {
            case PASSWORD_BCRYPT:
                // Note that this is a C constant, but not exposed to PHP, so we don't define it here.
                $cost = 10;
                if (isset($options['cost'])) {
                    $cost = $options['cost'];
                    if ($cost < 4 || $cost > 31) {
                        trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Invalid bcrypt cost parameter specified: %d", $cost), E_USER_WARNING);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                $required_salt_len = 22;
                $hash_format = sprintf("%s%02d$", PASSWORD_PREFIX, $cost);
                break;
            default:
                trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Unknown password hashing algorithm: %s", $algo), E_USER_WARNING);
                return null;
        }
        if (isset($options['salt'])) {
            switch (gettype($options['salt'])) {
                case 'NULL':
                case 'boolean':
                case 'integer':
                case 'double':
                case 'string':
                    $salt = (string) $options['salt'];
                    break;
                case 'object':
                    if (method_exists($options['salt'], '__tostring')) {
                        $salt = (string) $options['salt'];
                        break;
                    }
                case 'array':
                case 'resource':
                default:
                    trigger_error('password_hash(): Non-string salt parameter supplied', E_USER_WARNING);
                    return null;
            }
            if (strlen($salt) < $required_salt_len) {
                trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Provided salt is too short: %d expecting %d", strlen($salt), $required_salt_len), E_USER_WARNING);
                return null;
            } elseif (0 == preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9./]+$#D', $salt)) {
                $salt = str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode($salt));
            }
        } else {
            $buffer = '';
            $raw_length = (int) ($required_salt_len * 3 / 4 + 1);
            $buffer_valid = false;
            if (function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv') && !defined('PHALANGER')) {
                $buffer = mcrypt_create_iv($raw_length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
                if ($buffer) {
                    $buffer_valid = true;
                }
            }
            if (!$buffer_valid && function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
                $buffer = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($raw_length);
                if ($buffer) {
                    $buffer_valid = true;
                }
            }
            if (!$buffer_valid && is_readable('/dev/urandom')) {
                $f = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');
                $read = strlen($buffer);
                while ($read < $raw_length) {
                    $buffer .= fread($f, $raw_length - $read);
                    $read = strlen($buffer);
                }
                fclose($f);
                if ($read >= $raw_length) {
                    $buffer_valid = true;
                }
            }
            if (!$buffer_valid || strlen($buffer) < $raw_length) {
                $bl = strlen($buffer);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $raw_length; $i++) {
                    if ($i < $bl) {
                        $buffer[$i] = $buffer[$i] ^ chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
                    } else {
                        $buffer .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
                    }
                }
            }
            $salt = str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode($buffer));
        }
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, $required_salt_len);
        $hash = $hash_format . $salt;
        $ret = crypt($password, $hash);
        if (!is_string($ret) || strlen($ret) <= 13) {
            return false;
        }
        return $ret;
    }
```

Comment: Eu referenciei uma resposta que usa `openssl_encrypt`. Isso não é demasiado complexo para o exemplo dado? E podias explicar melhor o porquê de fazer essa implementação? Não era mais simples usar uma função alternativa? Há mais opções?! Eu uso as funções do tipo `password_` para palavras passe. Mas acho que não se justifica neste caso.

Comment: Na verdade, estou convertendo sua função depreciada em um método não depreciado, para atender o seu propósito, caso use senhas pré-existentes de seus usuários, o ideal é usar um método mais novo do php, que é seria password_hash, é muito mais seguro, veja na [documentação do php como utilizar](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: Ivan, eu já tinha referido a `openssl_encrypt` na pergunta, essa solução já foi respondida [noutra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318865/7210), o que eu quero são alternativas a isso, se existirem. A `password_hash` não faz sentido neste caso. Não estou a encriptar passwords.

Comment: O `password_hash` não tem haver com assunto, são propositos completamente diferentes.