# Login com certificado digital com PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde pessoal, estou tentando usar a api do certsign login https://www.certisign.com.br/produtos/desenvolvedores até aí tudo bem, consegui enviar a requisição e obter o retorno que é o token, só que na documentação ele só dar a opção de decriptar o retorno com JAVA ou .NET, gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com PHP?

Token retornado do certificado:

```
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
```

Script para decriptar o retorno com JAVA:

```
// obter retorno encriptado da resposta
String ret = request.getParameter("cb");

// obter chave que foi feito o download
InputStream chave =
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/keys/<sua_chave.pk>");

String schave = IOUtils.toString(chave, "UTF-8");

// usar client e chave para decriptar o retorno encriptado
String decriptado = CryptoLogin.decrypt(ret, schave);
</sua_chave.pk>
```

Script para decriptar o retorno com .NET:

```
string retorno = Request["cb"];
string encryptionKey = "<conteúdo da chave criptográfica descarregada na etapa 2>";
retorno = CryptoLogin.Instance.DecryptText(retorno,encryptionKey);</conteúdo>
```

Comment: O problema é que a página não especifica os algorítimos usados e não há nenhum lugar para saber onde é o "CryptoLogin.", já que não parece ser nativo. O "download do client" está com link quebrado.

Comment: como assim com link quebrado?

Comment: Quando clica em "Faça o download do client aqui.", e o "client" segundo eles é "Este client se refere ao componente de manipulação da chave criptográfica que rodará na sua aplicação.". Então, isto deve ser o código do `CryptoLogin`, tendo sorte. Mas, ao clicar ele não me permite baixar, então não tem saber quais são os algoritmos usados. Se você tem o `CertisignLoginClient-NET.zip` anexe aqui, assim qualquer um pode baixar e você mesmo pode ler o código ou dizer se ele é ou não o código referente ao `CryptoLogin`. Depois, sabendo os algorítimos de criptografia usado, dá pra replicar no PHP.

Comment: Segue o link para aplicação .net https://drive.google.com/file/d/14LZClYySfRomYmLYmtaGxmOeyLLsFQKT/view me passa seu contato aqui whatsapp ou telegram.

Comment: Estou vendo agora, parece fácil.

Comment: a aplicação está .net ou c#?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103113/discussion-between-bruno-santos-and-inkeliz).

Comment: A resposta funcionou ou não? Se achou outra solução pode inserir e depois marca-la como melhor resposta também.

Comment: pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 2):

> **AVISO:** Eu não possuo cadastro no Certisign, nunca fui cliente deles e não tenho qualquer vinculo. Além disso, esta minha resposta visa apenas ser "compatível", usando recursos nativos do PHP, com a menor quantidade de alterações possíveis em relação ao original, para que possa comparar e corrigir eventuais erros.

---

Uma vez que não tenho como testar, e afim de que você mesmo possa analisar por si, 
o código usado no `Decrypt()`, em `.NET` é exatamente:

```
   public string DecryptText(string encryptedString, string encryptionKey)
    {
      RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
      rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
      rijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
      rijndaelManaged.KeySize = 128;
      rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 128;
      byte[] inputBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString.Replace("certplus", "+"));
      byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey);
      byte[] numArray = new byte[16];
      int length = bytes.Length;
      if (length > numArray.Length)
        length = numArray.Length;
      Array.Copy((Array) bytes, (Array) numArray, length);
      rijndaelManaged.Key = numArray;
      rijndaelManaged.IV = numArray;
      return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length));
    }

    public string EncryptText(string textToEncrypt, string encryptionKey)
    {
      RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
      rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
      rijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
      rijndaelManaged.KeySize = 128;
      rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 128;
      byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey);
      byte[] numArray = new byte[16];
      int length = bytes1.Length;
      if (length > numArray.Length)
        length = numArray.Length;
      Array.Copy((Array) bytes1, (Array) numArray, length);
      rijndaelManaged.Key = numArray;
      rijndaelManaged.IV = numArray;
      ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor();
      byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
      return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length));
    }
```

O arquivo foi obtido [devido ao comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/430070/login-com-certificado-digital-com-php/430123#comment833318_430070).

---

Bem, primeiro eles usam `RijndaelManaged`, o `AES` usa o mesmo algoritmo. Por sorte, ele usam o mesmo padrão estabelecido pelo AES. Isso é, possui um bloco de tamanho 128 bits e tem uma chave de 128 bits. Eles usam o modo `CBC` que é comum, e não altera o tamanho dos blocos, *embora parecem usar de forma incorreta*. Já o padding parece que usa o mesmo *PKCS7*, exceto se especificado o `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`, daí nenhum padding é aplicado. Bem, no ruim podemos usar o obsoleto [`mcrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php), mas requer uma versão antiga do PHP e não recomendo usar.

Isso é uma tentativa com o `openssl`, se nada der certo tente com o `mcrypt`:

```
function DecryptText(string $encryptedString, string $key) : string {

    // byte[] inputBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString.Replace("certplus", "+"));
    $inputBuffer = base64_decode(str_replace("certplus", "+", $encryptedString));

    // byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey);
    $bytes = $key; // ?

    //byte[] numArray = new byte[16];
    $numArray = array_fill(0, 16, 0x00);

    //int length = bytes.Length;
    //if (length > numArray.Length)
    //   length = numArray.Length;
    $length = min(mb_strlen($bytes, '8bit'), 16);

    // Array.Copy((Array) bytes, (Array) numArray, length);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $numArray[$i] = $bytes[$i];
    }

    // rijndaelManaged.Key = numArray;
    // rijndaelManaged.IV = numArray;
    $_Key = implode($numArray); // ?
    $_IV = implode($numArray); // ? Isso é um problema de segurança! Me parece incorreto, exceto se a chave for usada uma única vez!

    return openssl_decrypt($inputBuffer, AES-128-CBC, $_Key, 0, $_IV); // ? Talvez usar o OPENSSL_RAW_DATA e depois converter para UTF-8?
}
```

Já com `mcrypt` seria algo como:

```
function DecryptText(string $encryptedString, string $key) : string {

    // byte[] inputBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString.Replace("certplus", "+"));
    $inputBuffer = base64_decode(str_replace("certplus", "+", $encryptedString));

    // byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey);
    $bytes = $key; // ?

    //byte[] numArray = new byte[16];
    $numArray = array_fill(0, 16, 0x00);

    //int length = bytes.Length;
    //if (length > numArray.Length)
    //   length = numArray.Length;
    $length = min(mb_strlen($bytes, '8bit'), 16);

    // Array.Copy((Array) bytes, (Array) numArray, length);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $numArray[$i] = $bytes[$i];
    }

    // rijndaelManaged.Key = numArray;
    // rijndaelManaged.IV = numArray;
    $_Key = implode($numArray); // ?
    $_IV = implode($numArray); // ?

    $_PaddingSize = ord($inputBuffer[mb_strlen($inputBuffer, '8bit') - 1]);  


    return mb_substr(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $_Key, $inputBuffer, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $_IV), 0, mb_strlen($inputBuffer, '8bit') - $_PaddingSize, '8bit'); // ? Talvez não precise remover o padding?!
}
```

*Talvez precisa converter o UTF-8 para Bytes, mas o PHP "não tem bytes", explicitamente, nem me lembro como era, talvez precisamos do `unpack` e do `pack`.*